# What is the most commonly used expression for "launching a factory or plant on an experimental basis"?

Tags: phrase-usage, terminology

I've already looked up phrases like "pilot commissioning", "test launch", "pilot launch", and many more. I can't think of anything that doesn't sound weird. Any comments?
This is the sentence I'm trying to compose: "10 percent of the contract price after ... and provisional handover". What should I replace the ellipsis with?

Comment: proof of concept?

Comment: Not quite. I'm looking for the right phrase for the "action of launching a factory/plant (for the first time) to see how it works".

Comment: *Piloting* (a plant) perhaps?

Comment: I don't think this is the right word specifically used in that context. I've run out of ideas and have a headache. Anyone else?

Comment: "the prototyping phase"?

Comment: Is this sentence supposed to be part of a contract?  If so, you should talk with a lawyer who speaks excellent English.

Comment: I think people are having trouble helping because it would be odd to build a whole factory on a trial basis. If you mean tool up a (pre existing) factory to start making a specific item, there will be more suggestions.

Comment: This is part of a contract between an employer and a contractor. The plant is supposed to be constructed and handed over by the contractor to the employer, who is going to operate it for the first time to see if everything works as agreed in the contract. If so, the contractor is going to receive the final 10 percent. If not, the contractor is required to fix any issues that may arise during this phase. This is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Jasper I don't have access to anyone who speaks excellent English, much less a lawyer. I'm hoping a lawyer will see this and help me out. Comments so far have been great, though.

Answer (score 1):

You either commission work or you do not. You either set up a factory or do not. Factories are not usually set up "on an experimental basis".

I think you might be looking for: **after the factory becomes operational on a trial basis**. Trial basis is used. Not experimental. Hope that helps.

Comment: Wikipedia defines "commissioning" as: "Project commissioning is the process of assuring that all systems and components of a building or industrial plant are designed, installed, tested, operated, and maintained according to the operational requirements of the owner or final client." From this definition, it seems the testing phase is included in the concept of commissioning. Maybe I can use "commissioning" here and replace the word "commissioning" I had used elsewhere with "operating", because I had originally used "commissioning" in the sense of "bringing into working order".

Comment: @HadiJafan OK, right. Here's scoop on the lingo. Commissioning is exactly that. So, you can say: being commissioned on a trial basis or become operational on a trial basis. Essentially, this has the same meaning, your choice. There is also (for your future reference) to bring on stream. My main point was "on a trial basis". Also, fyr, it's be or become operational or operate.